# How to declare looping (for) values as a variable

Tags: php

I wrote a looping function as below :

```
for($x=0; $x<5; $x++){
     echo "'$x'";
     if($x!=4){
          echo ", ";
     }
}
```

That will give result

```
'0', '1', '2', '3', '4'
```

How can i declare the result as a variable so that i could call and use it. For example, the result above is declared as $values. so that, i only need to call $values to get the '0', '1', '2', '3', '4'. Hope that's clear enough to deliver my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do it with least change in your code

```
   <?php

        ob_start();
        for($x=0; $x<5; $x++){
             echo "'$x'";
             if($x!=4){
                  echo ", ";
             }
        }
        $values = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $values;

        ?>
```

Comment: .. and will result in a totally unreadable and therefore unmaintainable mess.

Comment: this is what i meant, and it's working. why is it unreadable @phihag. i just wanna know the pros and cons by using this.

Comment: @Andha Because instead of constructing the string with output buffering, you can simply write `$values .=` every time you would use `echo`.

Comment: @andha all big frameworks MVC pattern uses this to build template nothing wrong with this approach . Some of the complex Tree data structure are not even possible without this . If my ans helped you then plz do accept it thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function:

```
$upToFour = range(0, 4);
```

Alternatively, you can construct the array in a loop:

```
$upToFour = array();
for ($i = 0;$i < 5;$i++) {
   $upToFour[] = $i; // Equivalently: array_push($upToFour, $i);
}
```

---

If you want to construct the resulting string, use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$upToFourString = implode(',', $upToFour);
```

, or, if you need the quotes:

```
$upToFourString = implode(',',
                          array_map(
                            function($num) {return "'" . $num . "'";},
                            $upToFour));
```

, or, equivalently,

```
$upToFourString = '';
for($x=0; $x<5; $x++){
     $upToFourString .= "'$x'";
     if($x!=4){
          $upToFourString .= ", ";
     }
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but how can i get all of the result by calling it with a variable.
so i don't need to write $upToFour[0] to get the values 0.

Comment: @Andha Sorry, I don't understand your problem. `$upToFour` now refers to an array already containing all values. You can iterate over the array with `foreach` or so. You should probably ask a new question, and include what *you're trying to achieve*, for example by specifying that the function takes an array and outputs a specific string.

Comment: i already edited my post, is it clear enough ? i want to declare the looping result so that i could call the result several times only by using the variable.

Comment: @Andha Nope, still not clear. *Why* do you want to do that, instead of simply iterating over the array? Also, can you post sample code that actually uses the desired functionality?

Comment: @Andha Do you want to store the *string* outputted by your original code in a variable? If so, I added code for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
for ($x=0; $x<5; $x++)
    $result[] = $x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply:

```
$a = array();
for($x=0; $x<5; $x++){
    array_push($a, $x);
}
```

Comment: The `$x != 4` condition refers only to the comma, not the value, and should be left out when constructing the array.